# Using Akka.NET FileIO.FromFile in a flow

Tags: akka-stream, akka.net

I want to embed a `FileIO.FromFile` in a graph, so that the `ByteString` output of this source can then be used.

In each attempt below, I use the same sink:

```
Sink<ByteString, Task<IImmutableList<ByteString>>> sink = Sink
   .Seq<ByteString>()
   .Named("sink");
```

To illustrate my difficulties, I will show a series of attempts, with full types:

First – using `FileIO.FromFile` as a source:

```
Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>> source = FileIO
   .FromFile(new FileInfo(fileName))
   .Named("source");

IRunnableGraph<Task<IOResult>> runnableGraph = source.To(sink);
IOResult result = runnableGraph.Run(Context.Materializer()).Result;
Log.Info(result.Count.ToString());
```

This compiles.

Now I want to use a `string` source and create from it a `ByteString` using `FileIO.FromFile`:

```
Source<Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>, NotUsed> source = Source
   .Single(fileName)
   .Select(x => FileIO.FromFile(new FileInfo(x)))
   .Named("source");

??? runnableGraph = source.To(sink);
??? result = runnableGraph.Run(Context.Materializer()).Result;
Log.Info(result.Count.ToString());
```

This does not compile as the type of source is a source of sources `(Source<Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>, NotUsed>)` which cannot be fed to the sink.

So then I tried using a flow to pass the `string` into the `FileIO.FromFile`:

```
Source<string, NotUsed> source = Source
   .Single(fileName)
   .Named("source");

Flow<string, Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>, NotUsed> flow = Flow
   .FromFunction<string, Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>>(x => FileIO.FromFile(new FileInfo(x)));

??? runnableGraph = source.Via(flow).To(sink);
??? result        = runnableGraph.Run(Context.Materializer()).Result;
Log.Info(result.Count.ToString());
```

This too fails to compile (although it is getting closer.)  The output type of `flow` is `Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>`, matching the type of the source in the first attempt, but still cannot be passed to the sink!

Why can the source of type `Source<ByteString, Task<IOResult>>` in the first example be passed to the sink, but the output of the flow in the last example not be?

Comment: What input do you provide and what is the output you expect? Do you want to feed it with sequence of file names and get a single source of `ByteString` with concatenated file contents?

Comment: I want to feed it a single string, do some transforms on the string to form a filename, feed the filename into a FileIO.FromFile, and consume the ByteString.